# Power Bank Improvements

Tags: power

I have 28 batteries at 3.6 V and some amps power. I have a pcb to get the power of the battery converted into 5 V. Now when I connect the PCB to 1 or 2 batteries it works to charges my phone, but when I add all of them together, with the same outcome voltage of 3.6, it does not work, the only thing that its high its the mAh, so any idea why its not working.

Oh, before I go, the PCB its not burnt out after using all 28 batteries at one and changing back to 1 or 2 its still working.

Comment: So you are putting batteries in parallel to get more current and everything works okay with one or two, but no longer works with many more added. (1) What is the battery chemistry here? (2) Why don't you try adding batteries one at a time and see where things go awry and then let us know what that experience shows you?

Comment: The battery are , cell litiun-ion battery , and it stops at 2 , the pcbi use its a cheap one that we can buy for £/$1 that comes with a battery , as a mini power bank.

Comment: Also, pictures can be helpful

Comment: i have sort it , i had a old power bank from tesco that had 10.000 mAh power and it works with that plus , bright side , it charges my laptop , so i can mine bitcoin for free yeyyyyy thx for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it do not work" is not usually enough information for anyone to diagnose the problem.

My guess is that some of your 28 batteries are either discharged or faulty and are taking current from the good batteries.

Test each battery alone, to try to find any bad batteries. Discard those. Then start to add the good batteries in parallel 1 at a time. If all the batteries are good then your phone charger should work.

Answer (score -1):

the pcb was week and i had to change it , now it works perfect.

Comment: You might want to write a more detailed description. How was the PCB weak?

Comment: As i am simply trying my luck with them i wood not be able to give that description the only difference between the pcb was the purchase of the power back it come out of  , the week one was £2 and the good one was £30